Intellij IDE not able to find the maven path
I am not able to set the maven path for the intelij IDE.
Also when I am trying to run the mvn --version in my intelij terminal it is not able to detect that as well.
Although, for my local terminal it is running fine
System: Fedora 38
enter image description here
I tried setting maven path in terminal also tried setting M2_HOME PATH variables

Did you install IntelliJ IDEA via snap? Does it help if you use .tar.gz version instead?
